# AWS ApiGateway and Lambda proxy integration - response structure clarification?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I already know that

[*For API Gateway to handle a Lambda function's response, the response must be JSON in this format:*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format)

```
{
    "isBase64Encoded": true|false,
    "statusCode": httpStatusCode,
    "headers": { "headerName": "headerValue", ... },
    "body": "..."
}
```

I've also verified it by checking [the doc's example](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents#function-handler) for a regular `Function Handler`.

[image]

But, looking at the [*second example*](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/2269c8142f38298df918aa3e58e986cdbc57dda3/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents/README.md) on the same page, it shows a serverless application lambda, which is actually a controller

However: the controller inherits `: ControllerBase` , and not `: Controller` as [I see when I create a new lambda serverless project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJnTI.jpg)
Also - I don't see that they use the same response structure as in the first example on that same page.

**Question:**

Why doesn't the second example forced to return the same fixed structure JSON as in the first example on the same page? and why the controllers base class are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there are several implicit questions lurking behind the original question. I would try to address your concerns to the best of my ability without taking to much of your time:

1. In your second example the AWS AspNetCoreServer takes the `IActionResult` (which is actually a `OkObjectResult`) and returns back something the lambda runtime can interpret as a response (same thing happens with APIGatewayProxyResponse). Responses to API Gateway are JSON documents with the structure below.

```
{
    "isBase64Encoded": true|false,
    "statusCode": httpStatusCode,
    "headers": { "headerName": "headerValue", ... },
    "multiValueHeaders": { "headerName": ["headerValue", "headerValue2", ...], ... },
    "body": "..."
}
```

2. `Controller` actually inherits from `ControllerBase` and adds some stuff to handle views (like the `View` method and `ViewBag`) and some other stuff. Here's an example of  controllers built using each approach.

```cs
[Route("[controller]")]
public class AnswerController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("")]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Answer answer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        // yadda yadda yadda
    }
}
```

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class AnswerController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("")]
    public IActionResult Post(Answer answer)
    {
        // yadda yadda yadda
    }
}
```

Comment: Also bith of your controllers inherit  the same base class

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear in the first item of my answer that the AWS `AspNetCoreServer` takes your controller response and builds a proper API Gateway response out of it, see the method `MarshalResponse` in `Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction`. You can keep the downvote if you feel like it

Comment: In the second example it should be `ControllerBase`, fixed now and thanks for noticing

Comment: Please read the answer (and my follow up comment) I think they explain how the process works in a concise and simple way. If there's something you think needs further clarification I would gladly provide an update to it.

Comment: I know that iactionresult can return anything. But in their example they dont return apigateway ProxyReaponse object. Why is that ?!?!?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207618/discussion-between-yorodm-and-royi-namir).

Answer (score 0):

[An answer from Norm Johanson](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/580#issuecomment-584916627):

> ❝The return of a controller method doesn't need to match what API
>   Gateway expects. It can return whatever you would normal want to
>   return back from a controller. The Amazoon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer
>   package that is hosting the ASP.NET Core application in Lambda takes
>   care of translating the response that came back from the controller
>   into what API Gateway expects.❝